# IPSEC configure over GRE tunnel in ubuntu

Tags: tunnel

I have created a GRE tunnel between to clients and they ping together but the problem is that as we know GRE  only encapsulates and does not encrypt the packets. I have seen thousands of tutorials on finding out how to configure Ipsec over GRE between two clients  in UBUNTU but I find for VPN ose for other systems. 
Has anyone idea for the code or the way I should install Ipsec in ubuntu for GRE??

Comment: Which version is ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @archismanpanigrahi ubuntu 18.04